# Cloudflare-S3 HTTPS handshake

Tags: amazon-s3, https, cdn, cloudflare

I've uploaded my static files to S3. To cache my files into CDN (and reduce aws cost + better SEO results), I'm using cloudflare.

My bucket name is `cdn.mydomainname.com`

My Cloudflare CNAME configuration is `cdn (name)` and `cdn.mydomainname.com.region_code.s3.amazonaws.com(alias)`

However, there's a problem. Whenever, I browse my webpages, the static files does not load because of `https` error stating `Your connection is not private`. Upon accepting it, my image url `cdn.mydomainname.com/image.jpeg` is redirected to `https://region_code.amazonaws.com/cdn-mydomainname-com/image.jpeg`. Now when I check my network logs, the image is not cache by Cloudflare, as I can see below in my response headers.

```
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: some_id
x-amz-request-id: some_id
```

I've read through multiple blogs, SO questions and documentation, but I'm not able to find the solution.

Some people recommend not to use bucket name as `cdn.mydomainname.com`. Instead use something like `cdn-mydomainname-com`.

Now my Cloudflare CNAME configuration is `cdn (name)` and `cdn-mydomainname-com.region_code.s3.amazonaws.com(alias)`

There are 2 problems with it.

1) My urls will not be pretty (https://region_code.amazonaws.com/cdn-mydomainname-com/image.jpeg). This will negatively impact my SEO.

2) It again shows the same response headers as shown previously.

```
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: some_id
x-amz-request-id: some_id
```

**What can be done to curbe this? Where am I wrong**

UPDATE

I tried to host a static file on my server, and that file is served from Cloudflare as checked in the response headers (CF-CACHE-STATUS: HIT)

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing CloudFlare's CNAME to

```
cdn-mydomainname-com.region_code.s3.amazonaws.com
```

but leave your bucket name as

```
cdn.mydomainname.com
```

and access your image at

```
cdn.mydomainname.com/myimage
```

S3 will use the hostname that CloudFlare sends when looking up the bucket not the subdomain.  Indeed you can put any subdomain in CloudFlare you want.  The important part is that the subdomain has no dots in it.  The certificate S3 presents to CloudFlare is a wildcard certificate of form

```
*.region_code.s3.amazonasw.com
```

so CloudFlare will accept it as valid for

cdn-mydomainname-com.region_code.s3.amazonaws.com

and the image will pass through CloudFlare as desired.